# Conduit Synchronizer Don't delete empty folder

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, sync, directory

I am using conduit sync tool for updating data from source(folder in local drive) to destination(folder in pen drive)

But when any  subfolder deleted from source, Conduit Only Removes all files from corresponding folders in destination BUT leaves folder as empty folder.

So, How to resolve this problem or Is there any other sync tool should I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can Synchronize between two folders/Directories by following command in Terminal:

```
rsync -av --delete "<path/to/source>" "<path/to/destination>"
```

Where `--delete` option delete also files/folders which doesn't contained by source and if exist (not-deleted) in destination.

So, I am using `rsync` which is best and suitable for me. Hope this helps